# CSS transitions on child element when hovering the parent

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm trying to figure out how to "animate" the child of a hovered element. How is this so complicated to get it work across multiple browsers?
what's the best practise?

```
.parent {
    -moz-transition:-moz-transform 180ms;
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 180ms;
    -o-transition:-o-transform 180ms;
    transition:transform 180ms;
}
.parent:hover > .child {
    transform: translate(0,-42px);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KKrdA/2/  works in firefox
or

```
.parent {
    -moz-transition:top 180ms;
    -webkit-transition:top 180ms;
    -o-transition:top 180ms;
    transition:top 180ms;
}
.parent:hover > .child {
   top:-42px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KKrdA/1/  works with webkit browsers

Comment: Why can't you combine the two: meaning why can't you have both `transform: translate(0,-42px);` and `top:-42px;` within the same rule i.e. `.parent:hover > .child`.  Or am I not understanding your problem correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

transform is not cross browser compatible you still have to target specific browsers.

```
.parent:hover > .child {
    transform: translate(0,-42px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-42px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0,-42px);
    -o-transform: translate(0,-42px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,-42px);
}
```

Comment: should have seen it myself. thanks! why is animating the `top` property such a pain though?

Comment: @yardarrat CSS positions are a pain in themselves. note that tranfoerm!= top